# html5 video plays on Firefox, Chome, IE10 but not on Opera or Safari

Tags: html, video, iis-7, opera, mp4

The following play the video on Firefox, Chrome and IE10, IE9 but not on Opera or Safari (and not IE8 but that is not really a problem) on Windows 8. The files are hosted on IIS. The mimetype set for mp4 is: video/mp4.

How do I get Opera and Safari play this?

```
    <video id='movie' controls autoplay ><!--video ist html5-->

    <source src='heiraten.mp4' /><!-- Quelle mp4-->
    <!-- 
    alle nicht HTML5 fähige Browser (IE8) machen hier weiter,
    mit flash, heiraten.swf ladet .f4v film
    und SkinOverPlayStopSeekMutVol.swf als controls
    -->

    <object id="myId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="640" height="360">
        <param name="movie" value="heiraten.swf" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="heiraten.swf" width="640" height="360">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <div>
            <h1>Alternative content</h1>
            <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
        </div>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>

</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Flash/swf.
Try it with the html5 Video Tag and use mp4 and ogg.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Thanks to "jop" for the note *.webm
I guess with this 3 formats the most Browsers will play your movie.

Comment: Note: Opera doesn't support mp4: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp, you should provide an ogg and webm version of your video aswell to support the most browsers.

Comment: Flash is needed for non html5 browsers.

Comment: Technology gracefully moved on rendering my question obsolete in the 00s. Nevertheless thanks for all the answers.